# Regex issue parsing Season / Episode pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Why doesn't this regex pattern parse the string "Season 02 Episode 01" properly?

For example, this is not a match:

```
var fileName = "Its Always Sunny in Philadelphia Season 02 Episode 01 - Charlie Gets Crippled.avi"

// Regex explanation:
// Starts with "S" and can contain more letters, can continue with space, then contains two numbers.
// Then starts with "E" again and can contain more letters, can continue with space, then contains two numbers. 
var pattern = @"S\w?\s?(\d\d)\s?E\w?\s?(\d\d)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` instead of `?`

`?` is for 0 or 1 time. `*` is for 0 or more times.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that was my mistake. This is the fixed pattern: `var pattern = @"S\w*\s*(\d\d)\s*E\w*\s*(\d\d)";`.

Answer (score 1):

> Starts with "S" and can contain more letters [...]

You mean `+`, not `?`.

```
var pattern = @"S\w+\s+(\d+)\s+E\w+\s+(\d+)";
```

Note that this regex is pretty unspecific. Watch out for false positives. I'd recommend to make the expression more specific.

Comment: +1 for `(\d+)`, which is an improvement of my regex. But on the other cases, `+` does not work (`*` does, as proposed by M.kazem Akhgary) because I expect 0 or more instances. What was not specified in the original post (and I am sorry about that, I took it for granted and I shouldn't have) is that `S02E01` is also a match. About "Watch out for false positives" you are right as well, but the input formats vary a lot so the pattern is generic on purpose.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, to catch `S01` you'd have to use the star. Pretty common way to write it, should have thought about that.